What is the best way of 8-Channel 2.54mm relay's pin terminal connection?
Well while I am developing small project I'm wondering how to make pin connections for ready-made modules. Such as this  8 channel relay

it has 2.54mm male header on it. if use jumper cable it dont looks so healty. Over time, vibrations can cause loose connections, which may lead to malfunction or even short circuits.

Removing components by desoldering and replacing them with JST jumpers can sometimes damage the PCB, rendering the module unusable. What kind of connection would you recommend for 2.54mm pin spacing that is crimped and resistant to vibrations? Many modules on the market are sold this way, so what approach should I take?

"Many modules on the market are sold this way" Many hobbyist modules, perhaps. Use some manner of proprietary board-to-wire connector. JST, Molex, TE, Samtech whatever flavour you prefer. Maybe replace it with a 2.54mm terminal block? Plenty to chose from then.

You can get multi-pin housings that will take the same contacts as the single-pin housings shown in your picture.

The single pin hobby jumper wires are pretty crappy. You can buy well-made contacts and crimp them onto wires and insert them into a quality housing sourced from a supplier like Digikey. The 'official' crimping tools are usually prohibitively expensive for hobbyists, but there may be some cheaper ones that are ratchet type and reliable enough.
